# How can I save the source of an image tag to a file?

Tags: javascript, php

Here is the problem:

I am getting a streamfrom a image overlay web service.

The string is something like this:

```
$string = http://[ipaddress]/faceCrop/Z%3A%5Ccelebhair%5CHair2-148_172_278_378.png/Z%3A%5Cprofilepictures%5C9ef14819f0.png/90/40/300/466
```

I then render the image out like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $string;?>">
```

This displays the image correctly.

However, I need to save the image (automatically) to a folder on the server.

How can I save the datastream as a physical image with either PHP or Javascript?

Thanks

J

Comment: Send the URL via AJAX to a PHP-Script which gets the file and saves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the contents of the file, and then save the contents..

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($filePath, $fileContent);
```